# Running Jython in ORacle Data Integrator (ODI) - how do I access the ODI packages

Tags: oracle, jython

If I load up jython in ODI, or run a procedure in ODI designer itself, I can

import com.sunopsis.dwg.tools
  import com.sunopsis.dwg.tools.ODIImportObject

but the only method available from ODIImportObject is main()

I want to run ODIImportObject in the same way I would from the command line using startcmd.bet, but hopefully reducing the cost of JVM start up each time.

but I cannot work out what to pass to ODIImportObject (the params I know, -filename etc, its how do i format the jython parameter to main() that gets me.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention which version of ODI you are using, In the latest sdk there are Service Finders for the different artifacts you want to retrieve. Eg. PackageServiceFinder etc...

Comment: 10.1.3.5.2
I am struggling just a little with the time it takes to import a single object - we have written procs to export each object as own XML file, meaning we can realistically put the whole thing in source control and still be able to have people work on non shared repositosries (ie do source control with ODI) but re-importing seems to invoke JVM then invoke Oracle connection then something else.  If you have any more details on using ODI with source control would be very interested.